# How to determine was site updated or not

Tags: object-model

How do I determine through API if a Sharepoint site updated or not? We are writing a tool that connects to Sharepoint site and downloads it on the local computer as a model. When someone adds or removes lists/libraries or changes list/library properties, the local model becomes outdated. Can I in simple way query remote site to determine such changes?

Answer (score 3):

SPSite.LastContentModifiedDate might be what you are looking for

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.lastcontentmodifieddate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have found the ChangeLog to work pretty good in these type of situations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447511.aspx